# Drupal: Drush module.. how to enable it?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is Drush supposed to be listed in Modules administration pages when I copy its folder there ?

I cannot see it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drush is not a module that you install like all other modules on drupal.org.

> drush is a command line shell and Unix scripting interface for Drupal

Which means, that it's something you use from the command line to stuff, it's a developer tool, it doesn't actually change your Drupal installation, but it allows to manipulate it.

- Download modules
- Enable/disable modules.
- etc.

Detailed info about installing drush, to your commandline interface, can be found in the README.txt file, that comes with drush.